# Insert POINT into postgres database

Tags: postgresql, postgis, node-postgres

I need to insert/update a point column type in postgres database.

I'm using `node-postgres`

The script generated using POSTGRES admin panel shows the update query as

`UPDATE public.places SET id=?, user_id=?, business_name=?, alternate_name=?, primary_category=?, categories=?, description=?, address=?, city=?, state=?, country=?, zip=?, point WHERE <condition>;`

How do I achieve point from latitude and longitude?

I have seen couple of answers using POSTGIS, but could not get it working.

In the documentation of POSTGRES (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/xfunc-sql.html) it is mentioned we can use `point '(2,1)'`, but this does not work with pg query.

What I have now :

```
var config = {
  user: 'postgres',
  database: 'PGDATABASE',
  password: 'PGPASSWORD!',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  max: 10,
  idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
};
```

And the update part :

```
app.post('/updatePlaces', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Update");
    console.log(req.body.places);
    pool.query('UPDATE places SET address = $1, alternate_name = $2, business_name = $3, categories = $4, city = $5, country = $6, description = $7, point = $8, primary_category = $9, state = $10, zip = $11', [req.body.places.address, req.body.places.alternate_name, req.body.places.business_name, req.body.places.categories, req.body.places.city, req.body.places.country, req.body.places.description, (req.body.places.point.x, req.body.places.point.y), req.body.places.primary_category, req.body.places.state, req.body.places.zip], function(err, result) {
      if(err) {
          console.log(err);
          return err;
      }

      res.send(result.rows[0]);
    });
});
```

Tried many different ways for passing point :

1. (req.body.places.point.x, req.body.places.point.y)
2. point(req.body.places.point.x, req.body.places.point.y)
3. point '(2,1)'

All the above throws error. Do I need to use POSTGIS?

Comment: It can be done automatically when using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise). If you are interested, then I will add an answer with examples ;)

Comment: Yes please @vitaly-t

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After couple of combinations, found out this works.!!

`( '(' + req.body.places.point.x + ',' + req.body.places.point.y +')' )`

Posting as answer if someone is trying to do this just using `node-postgres`.

So you can use single-quoted points: `insert into x values ( '(1,2)' );`

But using `insert into x values (point(1,2));` in the query does not work.

Answer (score 15):

This works if you write SQL "directly":

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE x(p point) ;
INSERT INTO x VALUES ('(1,2)');
INSERT INTO x VALUES (point(3, 4));
SELECT * FROM x ;
```

Results

```
(1,2)
(3,4)
```

Comment: Questions asked in Language X should be answered in Language X.

Answer (score 7):

I recently came across a similar problem using `node-postgres` when inserting into a `postgis` database with a geography (point) column. My solution was to use:

```js
pool.query("INSERT INTO table (name, geography) VALUES ($1, ST_SetSRID(ST_POINT($2, $3), 4326))",
      [req.body.name, req.body.lat, req.body.lng ]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Current versions (Postgres 12, pg 8) should work simply use Postgres's [POINT function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-geometry.html#FUNCTIONS-GEOMETRY-CONV-TABLE) to set a point column value.

Example:

```
export async function setPoint(client, x, y, id) {
    const sql = `UPDATE table_name SET my_point = POINT($1,$2) WHERE id = $3 RETURNING my_point`;
    const result = await client.query(sql, [x, y, id]);
    return result.rows[0];
}
await setPoint(client, 10, 20, 5);
```

Result:

```
{x: 10.0, y: 20.0}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), then custom types can be formatted automatically, see [Custom Type Formatting](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#custom-type-formatting).

You can introduce your own type like this:

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    // Custom Type Formatting:
    this._rawDBType = true; // to make the type return the string without escaping it;

    this.formatDBType = function () {
        return 'ST_MakePoint(' + this.x + ',' + this.y + ')';
    };
}
```

At some point you would create your objects:

```
var p = new Point(11, 22);
```

And then you can use such variables as regular types:

```
db.query('INSERT INTO places(place) VALUES(ST_SetSRID($1, 4326))', [p]);
```

See also: [Geometry Constructors](https://postgis.net/docs/reference.html#Geometry_Constructors).

Comment: Thanks @vitaly-t I have one more question, my database is more of location oriented, should I use postGIS?

Comment: Yes, it is generally a good idea, as PostGIS is like a native component for PostgreSQL these days, providing all the intelligent searches that one needs for location-based searches ;)

Comment: Cool. Thank you. :)

Comment: hey that last link is dead, do you have the current version?

Comment: that's perfect, just what I needed thanks